# Ошибка: TypeError: string indices must be integers (только в телеграм бот)

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, aiogram, битрикс24

Делаю телеграмм бота, в одном из хэндлеров получаю JSON:

```
pretty_json = json.dumps(tasksget, ensure_ascii=False, default=str)
```

```
[
   {
      "timeEstimate":"1800",
      "id":"573",
      "group":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "timeEstimate":"1800",
      "id":"575",
      "group":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "timeEstimate":"7200",
      "id":"577",
      "group":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

После, с помощью цикла я суммирую все значения "timeEstimate" (объектов в JSON может быть разное количество), вот цикл:

```
for item in pretty_json:
    duration += int(item['timeEstimate'])
    count += 1
```

Если код выполнять отдельно от бота, то ошибок нет, но если в боте тогда постоянно ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/local/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/home/local/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/home/local/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/local/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/home/local/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/local/Projects/helpdesk-bot/handlers/tasks_stat.py", line 55, in question_handler
    duration += int(item['timeEstimate'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: json.dumps преобразует словарь в строку json, нельзя у строки взять значение по ключу

Comment: Тот же самый код не в коеде бота выдаёт list, а в боте почему то string, это как?

Comment: читайте документацию https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: json.loads возвращает - list, но в коде бота, он почему то возвращает - string. Этот код в async def.

Comment: Оберните проблемный кусок в `try`/`except` и в `except` напечатайте или залогируйте в файл `item`, да и в целом `pretty_json`. Наверняка в `JSON` есть некоторые элементы списка, не являющиеся словарями, как вы ожидаете, а там обычные строки. Может там написана какая-то ошибка или ещё что-то, я не знаю что. Проверьте.